# Where can I purchase replacement parts for Battleship Galaxies?

Tags: battleship-galaxies

My boys and I still enjoy [Battleship Galaxies](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/93538/battleship-galaxies-the-saturn-offensive-game-set) in spite (and because of!) some rather bizarre abilities and the strange "activate only one ship" mechanic.

My younger son was setting up the board for a recent game and was a bit too overly enthusiastic when he disconnected the vertical piece of the base from one of the ship miniatures (it's a ball and socket press-fit attachment).  That snapped the tip off at a point that almost certainly doesn't have enough surface area to glue back together.

Is there a source for replacement parts?

For this specific situation, what we really need is hex bases of various configurations (1, 2 and 7 hex), with a vertical piece to hold up the ship mini and holes for the shield and hull pegs.

Comment: You can still glue them back together, but you'll need to add more surface area. Use a thin drill (1/16 inch?) to drill out both the snapped-off ball and the base, then insert a peg of some sort (such as a piece of paper-clip or toothpick). Then you can glue the peg into both broken bits, and it will hold much better than just gluing the broken bits together.

Comment: If you look at the pieces in the link that ire_and_curses added, you can see that the bases are some hexes, a vertical triangle with a pea-sized ball at the top.  The break was between the thin tip of the triangle and the ball.  Drilling would be close to impossible with my tools: there's just not enough plastic there to drill and add a pin.

Answer (score 3):

I did manage to find some replacement pieces from [here](http://www.litko.net/products/Galaxy-Battle,-Medium-Flight-Stands.html#.UrDRvvRDt8E).  As you see in the image below, the bases do arrive unassembled.  I'll use the plastic cement (that I ordered at the same time) to attach the vertical column into those center holes.

[image: My unassembled bases]

The part number at this vendor appears to be AFS062-CLR.

Note that, due to trademark restrictions (almost certainly), they have to refer to their pieces as "Galaxy Battle" and make them visibly different from the original.